# Generate a random word from list of words in back end and display it on front end

Tags: python, django, web, web-applications

I am new to Django and trying to learn more in detail. Currently working on a problem where I need to generate a random word from a pool of words and display it in the front end web page. I am able to generate the random word using python but wondering how to display the random word in the front end. Could you share some thoughts on this if you have encountered this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you working with the front end? With [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) you can interact directly with HTML.

Comment: Am using HTML/CSS along with Django to implement the front-end.

Comment: Stick it in the response when rendering the template.

Comment: Have you completed setup django and created app inside it, where exactly are you right now

Answer (score 0):

The Django templating engine allows you to pass data to the front-end simply.

To do so you first must create a template. Good practice for doing so is to create inside of the directory for your app (within the root directory for the project), a folder called 'templates' and inside of that create a folder with the same name as the app. So the full path would be something like: `myproject/myapp/templates/myapp`.

Inside of this folder, create an html file. This can pretty much just be a normal html file, but you can access variables passed to the template with this syntax: `{{ my_variable }}`. So so a span with your random word might look like: `<span>{{ random_word }}</span>`.

To render the view and pass the variable in from the controller, you might have something like this (in `myapp/views.py`):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def my_view(request):
    generated_random_word = generate_random_word()
    context = {'random_word': generated_random_word}
    return render(request, 'myapp/page.html', context=context})
```

The second argument of render is the template name (with the path starting from the `templates` directory). The third argument (`context`) is a dictionary where the keys are the names of the variables used in the template, and the values are the values for those variables. See the [documentation on render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) for more.

Alternatively, if you start to make a frontend that is more distanced from your backend (using, for example, React) you can create an API for your backend, which the frontend will call.

Comment: To be exact, Django *does not* use Jinja2 by default (although you have the option to use it). In fact, Jinja2 was modelled after Django's templating engine.

Comment: Ah, well this still applies. I just thought the templating engine was called Jinja2, but I guess not. I'll make an edit.